# MATLAB: Finding "Average" Index In Square Binary Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, average

Assume we have nxn binary matrix `M`. In MATLAB, I want to find the "average" index of points that correspond to 1.

To illustrate, the following examples are shown. A red circle indicates a cell value of 1, all other cell values are 0. The green x is the index that I want to return. A blue line of best fit further illustrates my point.

[image]

I am specifically looking for efficient code to do this. Anyone with some simple math skills can calculate this "average" index, but due to MATLAB's loop/iteration-based inefficiencies, I need to write fast code.

Comment: *but due to MATLAB's inefficiencies* what inefficiencies? Matlab can handle it pretty well. Matlab is very good at handling matrices.

Comment: Loops are extremely expensive in MATLAB. Particularly nested loops. In my specific case, what I am implementing is already in a nested loop, and so any additional loops would be highly undesirable.

Comment: Take a look at [Vectorization](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) in Matlab.

Comment: I understand the various methods of increasing performance in Matlab. This is beyond the scope of this question and ultimately irrelevant. However, for the sake of simplicity assume the above nested loops are unavoidable and thus the inner code need be highly efficient.

Comment: *highly efficient* in which sense? Also, in Matlab, you can call C code if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, by highly efficient I mean fast (space complexity is not an issue here). For our purposes here, let us call fast code any code that executes faster than code that would iterate over every index in the above matrix.

Ultimately I was hoping avoid calling C code to maintain simplicity for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
Rand_matrix=randi([0 1],3,3); %random binary matrix
[rows,col]=find(Rand_matrix);
row_mean=mean(rows);
col_mean=mean(col);
midpoint=[row_mean,col_mean]
```